# Conexão PostgresSql com o visual Studio

Tags: banco-de-dados

Boa noite, estou precisando conectar a base dados com o visual studio c#, porém não entendi ao certo como realizar e os materiais que encontro são meio confusos, se alguém puder ajudar ficarei grato, estou desenvolvendo um projeto para um sistema relacionado a nutrição e já estou com o prazo estourando, devido a este fato e tudo mais. Agradeço desde já!

Comment: qual a base de dados? Tem q dizer o que está usando ou qual pretende usar.

Comment: A base de dados que eu defini ontem é sql Server. Porém onde trabalhei eles tinham um webserver específico pra fazer as connections, por isso a dúvida, se puderes me ajudar ficarei muito grato, essa parte está me travando bastante. Obrigado!

Comment: já ouviu falar em string de conexão?

Comment: String de conexão já, só que o que acontece, trabalho como desenvolvedor ao todo tem 5 meses, onde trabalhei por 3 meses o webservice deles era sqld.ExecuteNonQuery("codigo do banco"); Porém fui ver e é diferente e as explicações até então estão meio confusas, não me deu um norte sabe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode criar uma Classe para isso:

Só que antes disso vamos adicionar uma `ConnectionStrings` ao `App.config` do seu projeto. Uma vez localizada e aberta o `App.config` antes da tag de fechamento `<\configuration>`, adicione:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="CaminhoSqlSever" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
           connectionString="Server=Nome do seu Server;
                             Database=Nome do seu Banco;
                             User Id=seu usuário;
                             Password=Seu password;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Feito isso adicione as referencias necessárias ao projeto:

```
using System.Configuration; //-> Com ele podemos acessar a ConnectionString criada no `App.config`
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Existem diversas maneiras de criar essa classe, abaixo segue um exemplo simples.

```
class ConexaoDB
{
    //-->Variavel que armazena a conexão.
    SqlConnection Con;

    //Propriedade que encapsula e retorna a conexão.
    public SqlConnection Conexao => Con;

    //Propriedade que retorna a string da conexão armazenada no arquivo de configurações.
    public string StrConexao => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CaminhoSqlSever"].ConnectionString;

    public ConexaoDB()
    {
        try
        {
            Con = new SqlConnection(StrConexao);
        }
        catch (SqlException erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Ocorreu um erro: {erro.message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, me ajudou bastante :)